# Reduce Ajax implementation time / latency?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I hava a page having multiple picture in grid view loaded though a php loop as follows

```
         <?php if($rows){
         $i = 0;
         while($resImage = mysqli_fetch_array($fetchImg)){?>

        <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="user-box">
        <h6 class="view-gallery-btn"><?php echo $resImage['image1']; ?></h6> 
        <?php $imgPath = base64_decode($_REQUEST['gallyId'])."_".$_SESSION['unique_id']; ?>
         <a href="Gallery/<?php echo $imgPath?>/<?php echo $resImage['image1']; ?>" download class="my-download-btn"><i class="fa fa-cloud-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
         <a href="order.php?gallyId=<?php echo $_REQUEST['gallyId']; ?>&photo_id=<?php echo base64_encode($resImage['id']); ?>" target="_blank"><img src="poweradmin/Gallery/<?php echo $imgPath?>/<?php echo $resImage['image1']; ?>" alt="" class="img-fluid"></a>
                <ul class="new-gallery-btn add-listing-gallery">
                    <li>
                       <a href="?status=<?php echo $resImage['id']; ?>"  class="change_status redFav user-default <?php if($resImage['myfavorite_userpic']== '2'){ echo 'user-fav'; }?>"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                       <a href="galleries_view.php?gallyId=<?php echo $_REQUEST['gallyId']; ?>&delt=<?php echo base64_encode($resImage['id']); ?>&page=<?php echo $_REQUEST['page']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <input name='ids[]' type='checkbox' id='ids' class="form-check-input custom-check-box checkboxes" value="<?php echo $resImage['id']; ?>">
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        <?php } } ?>   `
```

each image has a star icon that invokes an Ajax code as follows

```
    $("a.redFav").click(function(){
    var current = this ;
    var status_id = $(this).attr('href').split('=');
    var arr = status_id[1];
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'addUserPics.php',
        data:{arr: arr},
        success:function(msg){
            console.log("User Like Applied");
            $(current).toggleClass("user-fav");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

this calls a php file that updates the corresponding field in the database but the issue is that if there are many images in the page ( ie around 100+ ) and some of them are selected (ie the icon calling Ajax is clicked ) eg 10 only few of them are updated. Each time the success stats are different it seems that its due to Ajax call delay or incomplete calls. 
Kindly suggest a way to handle the same.

Comment: Can you clarify on what you mean by "some of them are selected"?  Given that they are links, they can't really be selected.  They are clicked.  So only one would be clicked at a given time.  You wouldn't have multiple links clicked simultaneiously.

Comment: I meant if I click assuming 10 links only 6 of them seem to work or sometimes 7 or sometimes all work fine so how to ensure each time all work fine ?

Comment: Browsers will limit the number of concurrent ajax requests that can be active at any given time.  Depending on the browser, if you try to make more, they may wait for earlier ones to finish before starting the new ones, or they may cancel the old ones.  There are at least two different ways you could go about this.  The first would be to wait for the previous ajax request to finish before starting the next one.  The second approach would be to figure out why your backend service is taking so long to respond.  You can't really do much about network latency, programatically.

Comment: could you suggest a way to implement the first solution you suggested ?

Comment: @OshoParth wouldn't PHP be able to tell you if the user has selected the start already? Why are you performing an AJAX call when you show each one?

Comment: I am calling Ajax to call php file to add and remove image from favourites